# Light status bar with dark text, API 21-22

Tags: android, statusbar

All stackoverflow answers say what there is no way to set light status bar with black text in API<23. But in my phone (API 22) many applications have light status bar (such as instagram, youtube, YAZIO). How did they do it?
[image: example]

My theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#colorPrimaryDak</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Hey i just found the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49255140/8089770